# Sqlite error (DataGrid)

Tags: c#, string, sqlite, datagrid

I do not know how to fix the Problem.
It's a sqlite query that should give the requested data record in the DataGrid.
When I enter numbers, it works!
But not when i enter letter's.

> SQLite error no such column: Example

My Code :

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection();
                connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Database.s3db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
                SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);
                SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                DataTable DT = new DataTable();
                connection.Open();

                command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string CommandText = "select Example from Lists where Example =" + textBox.Text ;
                DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, connection);
                DS.Reset();
                DB.Fill(DS);
                DT = DS.Tables[0];
                Grid.DataSource = DT;
                connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that Example exist in your table Lists and its type is of char, nvarchar or other character type then wrap your TextBox.Text in single quote like this

```
select Example from Lists where Example ='" + textBox.Text +"'" ;
```

However, try always to use parameter in your query.